# Bootstrap CSS fixed bg positioning

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a website based on bootstrap, html and css that has this structure in it's html:

```
wrapper for fixed footer at bottom {
  content
  fixed bg
  content
}
```

The wrapper around everything has a relative positioning. The fixed bg itself would be::

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0!important;
}
.fixed-wrap {
  clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#fixed {
  background-image: url('img/mac.png');
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<figure>
 <div class="fixed-wrap">
    <div id="fixed">
   </div>
 </div>
</figure>
```

The problem is that the fixed bg and content below aren't sticking to the right places. I think the problem here is my css.

With this css the fixed bg isn't shown at all. If i change the position of the figure to absolute it is shown, but the contact form overlaps it.
This is my first post here so sorry if it's a bit messy or i did something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height: 60%` of your `figure` will be 0 as it have to be the 60% of the parent element and your parent has 0 height. Try to define a parent element height in px. For example, `body` or any other parent tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was the height and i just set it to a fixed px value to fix it